# NetBeans 7.0 build output errors not hyperlinked

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html say:

> If the build output concludes with the statement BUILD FAILED, you probably have a syntax error in your code. **Errors are reported in the Output window as hyper-linked text.** You double-click such a hyper-link to navigate to the source of an error. You can then fix the error and once again choose Run | Build Main Project.

However, in NetBeans 7.0.1, the hyperlinks are mostly missing. (I'm running in Linux Mint 12.) The errors are plain text and navigating to them is a pain. This is true for all errors except for two at the end which are hyperlinked. The two that are hyperlinked are of no immediate use to me. They are:

> /home/user/Workspaces/MyApp/client.git/nbproject/build-impl.xml:603: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> /home/user/Workspaces/MyApp/client.git/nbproject/build-impl.xml:284: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

All the places I need to edit in the code are mentioned by file and line number, but are not hyperlinked:

```
MyApp.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MainView(com.example.desktopclient.MyApp)
location: class com.example.desktopclient.MainView
                    MainView mainView = new MainView(this);
```

Does anyone know anything about this issue. I searched but didn't find anything relevant.

EDIT: I'm NOT looking for help with the code errors! I want to find out why NetBeans isn't working correctly.

Comment: Use Netbeans 6.9.1 :) I tried EJB modules on 7.0 but found some other problems in the IDE. I think 7.0 have some problems.

Comment: why are you passing this as parameter? In MainView class do you have constructor with the object you are passing as parameter?

Comment: If you post some of the code around and including line 40, it would be easier to help with the error.

Comment: I'm not looking for help with the code errors. The code is irrelevant. I want to know why the errors are not hyperlinked. The problem has nothing to do with the specific code or a specific error in my code. This is an IDE issue. Thanks.